# Generate a random number sequence to get and average

Tags: algorithm, random, numbers

I am looking to generate a number sequence where each number is between 70 and 100 there will be x numbers in the sequence and it will give and average of y. What would this algorithm look like?

Comment: does the average of the numbers have to be exactly y or just when run many times come out to y on average?

Comment: Owe, perhaps I miss understood the question :-)

Comment: You won't get a good answer until you tell us the distribution. That is the hard part.

Comment: Duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39435481/how-to-generate-numbers-in-range-with-specific-average-with-python

Comment: Not a duplicate. The other question specifies that the numbers should not be random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is impossible for them to be uniformly distributed between 70 and 100 and have a given average at the same time.

What you can do is generate random numbers that have a given average and then scale them to fit into [70, 100] (but they will not be uniformly distributed there).

1. generate random numbers [0..1(
2. calculate their average
3. multiply all of them to match the required average
4. if any of them does not fit into [70, 100], scale all of them again by reducing their distance from `y` by the same factor (this does not change the average). `x[i] = y + (x[i] - y)*scale`

You will end up with numbers that are all in the range [70, 100(, but they will be uniformly distributed across a different (but overlapping) interval that is centered on y. Also, this approach only works with real/floating-point numbers. If you want integers, you got a combinational problem on your hands.

Comment: right, they can't be uniformly distributed. If y was 72 for example then the numbers between 70 and 72 must appear much more often than the numbers in 72 to 100 for them to still average to 72.

Comment: which is still *possible* to happen in a uniform distribution, but *extremely* unlikely. Uniform distribution implies that there are *no* restrictions on how the numbers are chosen.

Comment: by the way: do we want integers? Because if we do, this becomes a combinatory problem. My solution applies only for real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Python example

```
import random
import time

x     = 10
total = 0
avg   = 0


random.seed(time.time())
for x in range(10):
    total += random.randint(70,100)

avg = total /x

print "total: ", total
print "avg: ", avg
```

Comment: but here you want the "avg" to come out to a fixed number specified upfront.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Random r = new Random();
        List<int> l = new List<int>();
        Console.Write("Please enter amount of randoms ");
        int num = (int)Console.Read();
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            l.Add(r.Next(0, 30) + 70);
        }

        //calculate avg
        int sum = 0;
        foreach (int i in l)
        {
            sum += i;
        }

        Console.Write("The average of " + num + " random numbers is " + (sum / num));

        //to stop the program from closing automatically
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: no, part of the question was that the average must be specified before hand not found afterwards.