# Random Number Generator with given Interval and Mean in Python not C#

Tags: python, random

I am using `Python 2.7.12` with `Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)`. Trying to generate random numbers with the *random* package. I need to generate `n` numbers within an `interval` and their mean should be a `specified value`. For example:

I want `14` randomly generated numbers between `42,000` and `91,000` and I want these numbers to have a mean of `60,000`.

I know how to use random to produce integer numbers:

`random.randint(42000, 91000)`

and I can put this in a for loop, but, how can I adjust their mean as `60,000`?

Comment: How shall they be distributed?  Gaussian?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Random number with fixed average](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25761998/random-number-with-fixed-average)

Comment: How about generating them entirely randomly, calculating their mean and finally shifting them a bit to get the desired result?

Comment: search for 'mean' in the docs https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html, you'll find a few distributions

Comment: Doesn't matter for now. Let me see your solution procedure, please.

Comment: @JacobG python != c#

Comment: @JacobG. Yeah but that does not make the question a duplicate.

Comment: @JacobG. They want an implementation in Python I think

Comment: The problem with wanting a set of random numbers with specific properties ("their mean shall be 60") is that the two aspect contradicts each other. 
You can have a random number generator which will produce random numbers around a given mean.  If you take 14 of them that set will have a different mean.

Comment: @Chris_Rands I searched for 'mean in the link, however, couldn't get a similar case or couldn't understand what they mean. Can you please specify?

Comment: @Alfe, I exactly need 60,000 for the mean of those 14.

Comment: Any code suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while True:  # until a good sample was found
  s = [ random.randint(42000, 91000) for _ in range(13) ]
  v = 60000 + (60000 - (sum(s) / len(s))) * 13
  if 42000 <= v <= 91000:
    s.append(v)
    break
print sum(s) / len(s)  # will print 60000
```

This creates 13 random values from the standard generator and computes a 14th value so that the mean is exactly 60000.  Since the 14th value might be not in the given range, it tries this again and again until a valid 14th value is possible.

This is neither elegant nor nice.  But so was the question.

EDIT:

This approach will work for the given numbers but because it is retrying something, it might run indefinitely for different numbers (e. g. range = [42k, 91k], mean = 60k, count = 100k).

If you create 99999 elements randomly, their mean will be around (42k+91k)/2 and a single element used for balancing this back to 60k will not be enough (and thus always be outside of the range).  You could use a slightly more complex random number generator, producing random numbers between 42k and 91k with a mean of 60k (ask another question about this if you don't know how!).  Using this other random number generator will improve your chances of termination.

A second way to improve your chances of termination and thus finding a result is to build your result out of smaller chunks, each of them having the wished mean:  Create 5000 chunks of 20 elements with the method I presented.

You can combine both methods of course.

Comment: This is the best answer to a paradoxical question.  @user8028576, you are asking to build a discrete uniform distribution with `a=42000` and `b=91000`.  The problem is, mathematically the mean of this distribution should be _(a + b) / 2_ = 66,500, or the average of `a` and `b`, not 60,000.  So you are describing your distribution as _random_ when it is not; it exhibits skewness to conform to that lower mean that you want.

Comment: Answers my question. Thanks @Alfe.

Comment: The mean should not be 66,500 since there are not only two (min and max) numbers. There are 14 numbers.

Comment: @BradSolomon OP didn't mention uniform distribution at all.  Random numbers in a range [a, b] can still have a mean c ≠ mean(a, b).  Consider random() * random().  That will be in range [0, 1] but have a mean of 0.25, and all numbers will be completely random.  I considered coming up with a fancy formula, but since OP didn't want the *distribution* to have the specific mean but the *sample*, that wouldn't have helped anyway.

Comment: I realized that your formulation is not very effective for a large number of `n`, e.g., 150. Any other suggestion?

Comment: @user8028576 Please find my thoughts about larger numbers in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to generate random numbers between two values and a specific mean. Python has built in methods for some of these ways, but when I say there are a lot of ways, I mean it.

The simplest way would be to use a triangular distribution. `random.triangular(low, high, mode)` will produce a number from a distribution between low and high, with a specified mode. This might be good enough, but if you really want a mean, you can use the following function:

```
def triangular_mean(low, high, mean):
    mode = 3 * mean - low - high
    return random.triangular(low, high, mode)
```

If you wanted to get more complex, you could use a beta distribution by calling `random.beta(alpha,beta)`. These are really flexible and very weird; this image from Wikipedia highlights how strange they can be.[image: Beta distribution examples]

The mean of a beta distribution is `alpha/(alpha+beta)`, and the results are always between zero and one, so to scale it up to your use case, let's wrap it up in this function:

```
def beta_mean(low, high, mean, alpha):
    offset = low
    scale = high - low
    true_mean = (mean - offset)/scale
    beta = (alpha/true_mean) - alpha
    return offset + scale * random.beta(alpha, beta)
```

In the above function, alpha will change the shape of the distribution without changing the mean; it will change the median, the mode, the variance, and other properties of the distribution.

There are other distributions you could wrap in functions to fit your use case, but I'm going to guess that the above two will fit whatever use case you would like.

These will also produce floating point numbers, so if you want integers you'll have to cast them to integers, either by editing the functions or casting them explicitly after calling them.

Comment: I believe the OP is interested in fixing the _sample_ mean rather than the _population_ mean.

Comment: Probably, I couldn't get the function. But, when I run it one single time, I suppose it should yield 60,000 since we expect the meant to be 60,000. However, it yields 50585.37639745854, some random number which is not really close to 60,000.