# How to generate numbers in range with specific average with Python?

Tags: python, math

For example I would like to generate 22 numbers between 20 and 46 with an average value of 27. And I would like the numbers to cover the range as well as possible.

EDIT:
These numbers don't need to be random.

Comment: Isn't that the same as between `0` and `26` with an average of `7`?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are these to be "random" numbers or can we use a clearly ordered sequence? Just what do you mean by "cover the range as well as possible"?

Comment: These are not to be "random".

Comment: If it does not have to be random, what is the point of writing code for it? Just figure out a sequence and hard code it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating Random Non Integer Numbers with Constraints Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61432813/generating-random-non-integer-numbers-with-constraints-python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Warning: this is not the optimal solution but it works quite fast with your input parameters:

```
import random
from functools import reduce


def gen_avg(expected_avg=27, n=22, a=20, b=46):
    while True:
        l = [random.randint(a, b) for i in range(n)]
        avg = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, l) / len(l)

        if avg == expected_avg:
            return l

for i in range(100):
    print gen_avg()
```

In my laptop will give 100 random sequences in ~2.5s:

```
[21, 20, 20, 23, 25, 24, 29, 22, 42, 23, 31, 26, 30, 25, 29, 38, 20, 31, 46, 28, 41, 20]
[20, 30, 39, 26, 24, 31, 35, 36, 22, 22, 20, 32, 23, 21, 42, 32, 23, 24, 26, 28, 29, 25]
[23, 43, 21, 31, 44, 24, 24, 20, 27, 31, 28, 22, 26, 33, 25, 30, 21, 26, 33, 20, 31, 25]
[36, 28, 24, 29, 32, 21, 36, 28, 24, 27, 24, 22, 28, 28, 33, 21, 20, 32, 23, 30, 35, 21]
[21, 34, 25, 32, 20, 37, 31, 20, 46, 25, 21, 25, 35, 36, 21, 26, 21, 35, 24, 21, 30, 28]
[28, 23, 43, 22, 20, 23, 30, 41, 25, 32, 20, 21, 21, 30, 26, 22, 46, 40, 27, 26, 26, 21]
[21, 26, 38, 27, 42, 36, 43, 21, 29, 32, 22, 29, 26, 20, 23, 22, 21, 38, 23, 21, 21, 23]
[28, 21, 27, 34, 38, 21, 25, 37, 27, 22, 36, 38, 27, 20, 32, 35, 20, 24, 31, 22, 24, 24]
[28, 31, 23, 26, 36, 23, 30, 36, 32, 23, 20, 25, 23, 25, 25, 40, 21, 27, 21, 25, 28, 38]
[30, 24, 24, 25, 38, 27, 35, 31, 21, 31, 27, 22, 25, 25, 39, 31, 22, 23, 30, 29, 20, 23]
[25, 21, 42, 24, 24, 31, 22, 34, 32, 21, 23, 27, 20, 35, 31, 23, 26, 33, 20, 23, 22, 43]
[23, 23, 20, 40, 27, 22, 22, 41, 20, 21, 45, 26, 22, 28, 29, 39, 24, 23, 26, 34, 20, 38]
[22, 44, 27, 36, 29, 22, 24, 35, 30, 20, 20, 31, 38, 23, 20, 31, 25, 29, 30, 21, 24, 28]
[27, 30, 21, 28, 39, 30, 33, 33, 25, 21, 26, 33, 33, 24, 31, 20, 24, 25, 22, 27, 28, 20]
[23, 28, 24, 20, 35, 29, 33, 22, 23, 21, 31, 39, 32, 22, 24, 39, 22, 21, 29, 32, 34, 25]
[38, 25, 20, 22, 21, 44, 32, 20, 26, 20, 21, 29, 25, 20, 37, 27, 33, 23, 20, 39, 28, 27]
[29, 22, 30, 20, 31, 23, 23, 24, 28, 28, 46, 27, 24, 23, 21, 35, 20, 21, 45, 29, 27, 34]
[21, 29, 21, 33, 38, 44, 21, 20, 41, 30, 26, 23, 23, 29, 21, 32, 20, 29, 32, 29, 21, 26]
[21, 20, 24, 40, 30, 30, 31, 27, 20, 34, 28, 37, 31, 20, 38, 43, 25, 25, 21, 20, 27, 22]
[27, 35, 30, 21, 36, 37, 41, 21, 23, 24, 23, 32, 23, 25, 20, 23, 36, 40, 30, 24, 20, 24]
[39, 30, 30, 21, 26, 23, 20, 25, 36, 22, 23, 29, 23, 42, 20, 23, 32, 20, 30, 36, 25, 31]
[24, 24, 25, 41, 20, 27, 35, 31, 21, 24, 31, 36, 20, 25, 22, 32, 31, 30, 21, 22, 33, 25]
[22, 34, 33, 20, 29, 24, 34, 27, 27, 31, 20, 24, 22, 33, 36, 22, 21, 31, 21, 38, 21, 44]
[20, 43, 29, 23, 22, 32, 20, 21, 26, 23, 26, 33, 34, 22, 26, 20, 38, 21, 29, 32, 24, 33]
[23, 38, 39, 35, 21, 33, 25, 39, 33, 28, 23, 20, 22, 22, 25, 30, 20, 26, 28, 31, 24, 30]
[21, 36, 32, 42, 25, 25, 20, 46, 24, 22, 22, 22, 33, 32, 22, 29, 24, 26, 30, 23, 22, 21]
[25, 34, 20, 23, 44, 21, 40, 21, 25, 20, 26, 25, 44, 20, 24, 32, 21, 23, 31, 21, 43, 22]
[34, 31, 23, 20, 25, 30, 22, 23, 30, 22, 31, 21, 41, 42, 21, 22, 36, 20, 26, 24, 31, 32]
[27, 27, 35, 34, 31, 36, 21, 21, 24, 39, 22, 29, 29, 20, 20, 46, 23, 30, 27, 24, 28, 21]
[28, 37, 30, 31, 38, 23, 21, 20, 21, 32, 29, 24, 32, 20, 20, 21, 28, 20, 32, 41, 25, 40]
[27, 25, 24, 46, 23, 24, 26, 28, 30, 23, 23, 27, 38, 20, 44, 21, 27, 25, 20, 23, 26, 28]
[20, 28, 24, 33, 25, 22, 28, 27, 22, 27, 42, 25, 43, 27, 20, 26, 29, 33, 29, 24, 36, 23]
[39, 31, 27, 20, 23, 25, 22, 22, 24, 26, 25, 42, 21, 22, 21, 21, 28, 24, 44, 31, 35, 34]
[20, 20, 31, 30, 41, 30, 40, 20, 28, 20, 21, 25, 23, 30, 28, 25, 29, 21, 28, 28, 38, 24]
[35, 37, 30, 20, 24, 25, 36, 21, 23, 29, 25, 23, 21, 27, 22, 44, 41, 24, 33, 30, 22, 20]
[22, 22, 25, 20, 22, 29, 25, 25, 21, 33, 23, 20, 21, 42, 39, 32, 33, 30, 46, 34, 21, 22]
[26, 25, 27, 35, 30, 39, 20, 26, 43, 20, 29, 33, 23, 27, 35, 21, 20, 36, 24, 27, 21, 28]
[20, 30, 24, 31, 36, 23, 24, 46, 30, 28, 24, 25, 24, 22, 20, 33, 20, 21, 24, 23, 39, 27]
[20, 22, 33, 22, 33, 22, 38, 24, 29, 36, 23, 31, 26, 24, 28, 28, 26, 28, 43, 24, 25, 20]
[36, 26, 24, 24, 24, 33, 21, 28, 27, 29, 31, 31, 21, 27, 25, 24, 34, 20, 33, 37, 23, 30]
[25, 33, 24, 27, 30, 35, 25, 30, 23, 23, 20, 20, 28, 30, 29, 38, 25, 25, 32, 21, 25, 33]
[30, 21, 27, 33, 21, 43, 23, 23, 25, 29, 23, 38, 28, 24, 21, 44, 22, 31, 32, 21, 20, 27]
[21, 33, 26, 26, 33, 27, 26, 32, 41, 31, 25, 29, 33, 22, 26, 38, 24, 22, 21, 28, 21, 21]
[26, 28, 31, 20, 38, 20, 26, 23, 24, 24, 30, 21, 21, 33, 26, 33, 38, 28, 40, 24, 21, 26]
[21, 27, 30, 22, 24, 28, 38, 27, 20, 23, 41, 20, 26, 41, 26, 24, 29, 22, 20, 43, 21, 42]
[22, 28, 21, 25, 25, 46, 29, 27, 24, 34, 24, 27, 23, 23, 34, 21, 37, 26, 20, 44, 28, 24]
[32, 27, 21, 35, 28, 37, 21, 32, 23, 20, 21, 20, 31, 21, 32, 24, 35, 26, 42, 35, 22, 24]
[22, 36, 41, 35, 27, 20, 25, 21, 28, 32, 31, 30, 23, 26, 23, 26, 28, 33, 23, 35, 20, 23]
[28, 24, 27, 39, 37, 25, 21, 29, 36, 27, 24, 24, 26, 27, 37, 27, 28, 23, 27, 21, 22, 26]
[32, 33, 24, 31, 22, 35, 39, 20, 39, 39, 22, 21, 23, 28, 34, 23, 20, 21, 35, 24, 23, 22]
[25, 20, 20, 25, 28, 23, 37, 30, 34, 27, 22, 20, 41, 22, 22, 23, 42, 27, 39, 25, 22, 24]
[20, 36, 22, 21, 21, 38, 20, 45, 36, 28, 23, 23, 35, 26, 20, 30, 31, 28, 33, 22, 25, 31]
[30, 23, 21, 45, 20, 31, 35, 21, 22, 24, 29, 32, 34, 30, 23, 31, 20, 20, 31, 35, 29, 20]
[22, 21, 22, 32, 42, 24, 35, 22, 26, 21, 28, 23, 24, 21, 31, 20, 27, 39, 42, 21, 37, 33]
[26, 28, 24, 20, 42, 23, 22, 20, 22, 33, 24, 25, 24, 28, 38, 26, 44, 28, 31, 20, 28, 25]
[25, 42, 32, 20, 25, 20, 27, 22, 21, 20, 31, 28, 21, 31, 25, 25, 46, 28, 30, 41, 25, 20]
[20, 27, 28, 26, 34, 23, 20, 22, 34, 20, 36, 30, 21, 23, 26, 23, 31, 37, 23, 34, 40, 29]
[28, 30, 22, 21, 20, 35, 20, 24, 23, 24, 34, 33, 37, 34, 24, 21, 24, 21, 41, 32, 22, 30]
[21, 20, 21, 28, 24, 42, 36, 26, 29, 33, 26, 22, 33, 28, 26, 31, 20, 22, 29, 32, 27, 28]
[23, 41, 24, 39, 22, 23, 25, 21, 24, 35, 20, 27, 31, 43, 34, 29, 24, 22, 23, 21, 37, 21]
[20, 29, 32, 21, 27, 25, 32, 36, 24, 34, 33, 31, 25, 21, 29, 26, 21, 32, 23, 33, 20, 29]
[21, 32, 22, 26, 40, 40, 23, 28, 26, 25, 31, 21, 20, 37, 30, 30, 25, 35, 27, 24, 24, 21]
[25, 25, 27, 21, 27, 23, 20, 39, 20, 43, 29, 21, 38, 27, 30, 23, 24, 29, 20, 24, 36, 30]
[26, 20, 22, 25, 28, 22, 21, 29, 30, 37, 23, 39, 20, 34, 33, 23, 25, 30, 27, 41, 27, 26]
[29, 20, 32, 22, 26, 27, 21, 20, 27, 26, 22, 42, 28, 24, 26, 23, 40, 24, 27, 42, 23, 44]
[21, 38, 25, 26, 35, 28, 21, 40, 37, 28, 25, 23, 26, 22, 22, 21, 46, 29, 23, 23, 21, 32]
[39, 23, 20, 37, 26, 22, 30, 21, 25, 25, 32, 20, 39, 20, 33, 23, 24, 32, 38, 22, 33, 27]
[21, 21, 21, 20, 34, 20, 27, 36, 25, 20, 20, 26, 34, 40, 32, 32, 30, 22, 28, 29, 36, 35]
[37, 30, 23, 20, 21, 38, 26, 21, 41, 34, 33, 26, 36, 26, 25, 34, 34, 20, 24, 21, 20, 25]
[28, 24, 25, 29, 41, 24, 24, 29, 34, 37, 20, 29, 21, 30, 21, 28, 33, 20, 22, 43, 27, 20]
[35, 36, 20, 29, 26, 30, 26, 26, 34, 22, 24, 25, 21, 35, 34, 34, 25, 21, 23, 31, 24, 20]
[24, 25, 22, 22, 31, 28, 38, 42, 33, 24, 37, 27, 21, 42, 22, 28, 25, 20, 21, 25, 22, 29]
[26, 38, 33, 40, 22, 22, 21, 26, 29, 26, 23, 25, 35, 21, 27, 23, 35, 21, 43, 29, 20, 29]
[26, 31, 25, 20, 20, 21, 25, 25, 24, 28, 22, 30, 22, 22, 40, 37, 29, 46, 20, 38, 22, 24]
[24, 26, 23, 22, 34, 26, 30, 20, 24, 21, 32, 24, 24, 31, 31, 27, 28, 31, 32, 45, 25, 33]
[30, 32, 24, 27, 24, 21, 25, 22, 23, 39, 39, 22, 27, 23, 37, 23, 32, 23, 38, 21, 36, 22]
[27, 23, 22, 24, 28, 42, 26, 33, 28, 20, 20, 35, 22, 20, 31, 27, 34, 23, 32, 36, 23, 38]
[31, 35, 23, 28, 21, 28, 37, 20, 38, 34, 27, 20, 24, 27, 22, 26, 20, 29, 35, 31, 28, 21]
[28, 21, 33, 31, 24, 29, 20, 23, 25, 22, 28, 27, 30, 25, 29, 28, 26, 22, 38, 39, 30, 33]
[23, 36, 41, 26, 23, 29, 29, 45, 20, 23, 34, 21, 22, 39, 35, 24, 20, 24, 24, 25, 23, 28]
[25, 25, 21, 32, 44, 24, 32, 28, 33, 21, 22, 38, 32, 22, 25, 29, 22, 27, 29, 26, 26, 32]
[35, 28, 35, 24, 27, 34, 25, 30, 25, 42, 29, 26, 20, 36, 25, 25, 20, 20, 23, 21, 31, 34]
[44, 23, 20, 25, 24, 28, 20, 23, 38, 21, 24, 28, 35, 30, 20, 45, 23, 28, 39, 26, 23, 25]
[22, 25, 22, 45, 21, 22, 31, 37, 42, 28, 21, 24, 26, 25, 30, 25, 20, 36, 23, 25, 23, 29]
[32, 21, 28, 20, 20, 41, 25, 20, 46, 21, 38, 31, 25, 26, 21, 30, 20, 31, 39, 24, 22, 24]
[34, 24, 23, 26, 33, 20, 26, 26, 24, 20, 24, 25, 21, 29, 31, 30, 39, 34, 28, 27, 25, 41]
[26, 36, 20, 27, 23, 23, 20, 27, 32, 23, 24, 36, 34, 23, 24, 43, 25, 25, 33, 24, 31, 31]
[23, 21, 28, 20, 33, 46, 20, 43, 21, 24, 28, 21, 22, 34, 38, 25, 20, 20, 20, 25, 44, 32]
[30, 35, 26, 21, 28, 20, 21, 22, 24, 35, 23, 22, 21, 26, 24, 31, 41, 37, 27, 20, 43, 25]
[34, 42, 21, 20, 26, 21, 40, 20, 41, 21, 21, 23, 29, 22, 21, 26, 30, 25, 32, 29, 39, 27]
[31, 44, 40, 27, 22, 21, 44, 21, 30, 26, 20, 34, 22, 20, 20, 20, 29, 36, 22, 21, 22, 38]
[21, 43, 46, 28, 32, 22, 23, 21, 24, 21, 28, 21, 20, 33, 21, 24, 36, 22, 23, 28, 45, 32]
[21, 22, 24, 39, 21, 25, 25, 20, 23, 20, 22, 26, 40, 39, 22, 28, 41, 38, 20, 20, 33, 33]
[34, 22, 26, 23, 28, 20, 32, 25, 24, 20, 39, 28, 41, 24, 29, 32, 24, 33, 23, 34, 24, 23]
[22, 39, 36, 22, 24, 20, 28, 23, 30, 39, 23, 33, 37, 25, 27, 20, 23, 27, 34, 31, 25, 20]
[34, 20, 20, 22, 26, 21, 26, 40, 23, 20, 42, 23, 31, 25, 46, 31, 27, 28, 22, 31, 34, 23]
[24, 29, 39, 24, 39, 26, 25, 25, 29, 23, 27, 20, 46, 21, 27, 25, 20, 41, 24, 31, 25, 22]
[42, 25, 23, 30, 22, 23, 37, 20, 29, 32, 28, 22, 35, 36, 22, 20, 27, 39, 21, 20, 22, 32]
[24, 26, 37, 44, 26, 23, 21, 23, 34, 33, 36, 22, 22, 22, 21, 27, 35, 24, 22, 44, 21, 20]
[24, 27, 22, 30, 20, 27, 21, 24, 31, 22, 30, 33, 35, 24, 23, 20, 32, 28, 30, 44, 26, 29]
```

Comment: To tackle this brute-force approach, we can do something like updating the range after picking a number based on the current average so that the final average is as required.

Comment: Is it required to use reduce or can we use sum?

Answer (score 3):

You could sove this in a pure mathematical way.

1. Randomly pick a number (call it n) within the wanted range
2. The next number will be avg + abs(n-avg)
3. repeat this until you fill the amount of numbers you want

if the amount of needed numbers is no even - just select one of the numbers as the average itself and then you will need to generate k-1 numbers (which is even)

** **EDIT** **
you can use this code that manipulates an initial list to meet the requirements of a average so the resulting list is not symmetrical. (Better than generating lists until you hit the correct one)

```
import random


def generate_numbers(wanted_avg, numbers_to_generate, start, end):
    rng = [i for i in range(start, end)]
    initial_selection = [random.choice(rng) for _ in range(numbers_to_generate)]
    initial_avg = reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, initial_selection) / float(numbers_to_generate)
    print "initial selection is: " + str(initial_selection)
    print "initial avg is: " + str(initial_avg)
    if initial_avg == wanted_avg:
        return initial_selection
    off = abs(initial_avg - wanted_avg)
    manipulation = off * numbers_to_generate

    sign = -1 if initial_avg > wanted_avg else 1

    manipulation_action = dict()
    acceptable_indices = range(numbers_to_generate)
    while manipulation > 0:
        random_index = random.choice(acceptable_indices)
        factor = manipulation_action[random_index] if random_index in manipulation_action else 0
        after_manipulation = initial_selection[random_index] + factor + sign * 1
        if start <= after_manipulation <= end:
            if random_index in manipulation_action:
                manipulation_action[random_index] += sign * 1
                manipulation -= 1
            else:
                manipulation_action[random_index] = sign * 1
                manipulation -= 1
        else:
            acceptable_indices.remove(random_index)

    for key in manipulation_action:
        initial_selection[key] += manipulation_action[key]

    print "after manipulation selection is: " + str(initial_selection)
    print "after manipulation avg is: " + str(reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, initial_selection) / float(numbers_to_generate))
    return initial_selection
```

Comment: The generated sets will always be symmetrical though. (If we assume that necessary checks are employed to ensure the calculated next number is within range)

Comment: if you don't want symmetry, you can generate n random numbers from within a range and see the distance of their avg from the wanted avg and manipulate  a random subset of the generated numbers to adjust and fix the avg. But in this case you cant assure that the distribution of the generated numbers is uniform across the range.

Answer (score 2):

So I also used the random number generator. In addition, in order to meet the specification to cover the range as well as possible, I also calculated the standard deviation, which is a good measure of spread. So whenever a sample set meets the criteria of mean of 27, I compared it to previous matches and constantly choose the samples that have the highest std dev (mean always = 27). SO in my script, I did 5 trials, and you can see the output that the final answer matches the samples_list that had highest std dev. Note that Python 3.4 or higher is needed to use statistics module. If you're using Python 2, then you can replace the stdev function with of your own (which you can easily find on Google or Stackoverflow)

```
import random as rd
import statistics as st
min_val = 20
max_val = 46
sample_count = 22
expected_mean = 27
num_of_trials = 5

def get_samples_list(min_v, max_v, s_count, exp_mean):
    target_sum = sample_count * expected_mean
    samples_list = []
    curr_stdev_max = 0
    for trials in range(num_of_trials):
        samples = [0] * sample_count
        while sum(samples) != target_sum:
            samples = [rd.randint(min_v, max_v) for trial in range(s_count)]
        print ("Mean: ", st.mean(samples), "Std Dev: ", st.stdev(samples), )
        print (samples, "\n")
        if st.stdev(samples) > curr_stdev_max:
            curr_stdev_max = st.stdev(samples)
            samples_best = samples[:]
    return samples_best

samples_list = get_samples_list(min_val, max_val, sample_count, expected_mean)
print ("\nFinal list: ",samples_list)
samples_list.sort()
print ("\nSorted Final list: ",samples_list)
```

Here is the output:

```
Mean:  27 Std Dev:  6.90755280213519
[34, 30, 39, 21, 23, 32, 22, 23, 22, 20, 27, 30, 29, 20, 32, 24, 42, 20, 39, 24, 20, 21] 

Mean:  27 Std Dev:  6.07100838882165
[21, 21, 34, 27, 35, 22, 29, 34, 24, 21, 20, 22, 20, 23, 26, 29, 28, 31, 30, 41, 21, 35] 

Mean:  27 Std Dev:  6.2105900340811875
[26, 27, 26, 26, 25, 42, 32, 23, 21, 34, 23, 20, 25, 25, 21, 27, 40, 21, 26, 26, 37, 21] 

Mean:  27 Std Dev:  8.366600265340756
[27, 22, 22, 44, 41, 21, 28, 36, 21, 23, 21, 25, 20, 20, 39, 46, 23, 25, 21, 23, 20, 26] 

Mean:  27 Std Dev:  6.347102826149446
[21, 30, 20, 41, 25, 23, 39, 26, 27, 20, 28, 23, 29, 24, 20, 40, 27, 27, 22, 25, 34, 23] 


Final list:  [27, 22, 22, 44, 41, 21, 28, 36, 21, 23, 21, 25, 20, 20, 39,
 46, 23, 25, 21, 23, 20, 26]

Sorted Final list:  [20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 23, 23, 23, 25, 25,
 26, 27, 28, 36, 39, 41, 44, 46]
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not optimal in terms of covering the range as much as possible, but you can try this:

```
def GenerateArr(count,minimum,maximum,average):
    arr = []
    diff = 1
    while len(arr) < count-1:
        if minimum <= average-diff and average+diff <= maximum:
            arr.append(average-diff)
            arr.append(average+diff)
            diff += 1
        else:
            arr.append(average)
            diff = 1
    if len(arr) < count:
        arr.append(average)
    return arr

print GenerateArr(22,20,46,27)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used an iterative approach to continuously track the current avg and the target avg while generating the numbers. Every step is directed towards bringing the cur_avg towards the target while using the RNG/

```
import random

def gen_target_avg(num, min, max, avg):
    numbers = []
    sum = 0
    cur_avg = max
    print "Current avg is %f: %r" % (cur_avg, numbers)
    for n in range(0, num):
        if avg < cur_avg:
            n = random.randint(min, cur_avg)
            sum  += n
            numbers.append(n)
        elif avg > cur_avg:
            n = random.randint(cur_avg, max)
            sum += n
            numbers.append(n)
        cur_avg = sum/len(numbers)
    print "Final avg is %f: %r" % (cur_avg, numbers)

>>> gen_target_avg(100, 3, 150, 25)
Current avg is 150.000000: []
Final avg is 25.000000: [81, 47, 56, 58, 23, 27, 24, 3, 7, 11, 19, 15, 19, 11, 18, 14, 24, 20, 17, 3, 121, 16, 7, 24, 6, 14, 13]
>>> gen_target_avg(100, 3, 150, 25)  
Current avg is 150.000000: []
Final avg is 25.000000: [56, 3, 14, 139, 10, 10, 11, 34, 22, 26, 31, 24, 16,   19, 11, 28, 28, 6, 25, 19, 25, 17, 21]
>>> gen_target_avg(100, 3, 150, 30)
Current avg is 150.000000: []
Final avg is 30.000000: [143, 131, 38, 54, 34, 75, 31, 11, 63, 42, 38, 4, 22, 46, 27, 13, 6, 17, 14, 6, 21, 15, 3, 30, 15, 29, 28, 4, 32, 9, 17, 22, 10, 28, 11, 26]
```